# Limit scope of NSMetadataQuery

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, spotlight

I was trying to restrict the scope of an `NSMetadataQuery` item. I know there's the *-setSearchScope:* method (see the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMetadataQuery_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMetadataQuery/setSearchScopes%3a)), but it lets me only decide in which directories the item will search.

What if I need to **exclude** one or more directories from the scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe this is possible, since the `kMDItemPath` attribute is not indexed by Spotlight, and is therefore not usable in a query.

[File a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to set all the include paths in the setSearchScope array, leaving out what you don't want. Of course that is only good if you know those ahead of time.